# ReactiveCocoa sequencing with async network requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, functional-programming, reactive-cocoa

I'm building a demonstration app and am trying to conform to the [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) [design pattern](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/DesignGuidelines.md) as much as possible. Here's what the app does:

- Find the device's location
- Whenever the location key changes, fetch:

  - Current weather
  - Hourly forecast
  - Daily forecast

So the order is 1) update location 2) merge all 3 weather fetches. I've built a `WeatherManager` singleton that exposes weather objects, location information, and methods to manually update. This singleton conforms to the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol. The location code is very basic, so I'm leaving it out. The only real point of interest is this:

```objc
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    // omitting accuracy & cache checking
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    self.currentLocation = location;
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Fetching the weather conditions is all very similar, so I've built a method to generate a `RACSignal` for fetching JSON from a URL.

```objc
- (RACSignal *)fetchJSONFromURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if (! error) {
                NSError *jsonError = nil;
                id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
                if (! jsonError) {
                    [subscriber sendNext:json];
                }
                else {
                    [subscriber sendError:jsonError];
                }
            }
            else {
                [subscriber sendError:error];
            }

            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }];

        [dataTask resume];

        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
            [dataTask cancel];
        }];
    }];
}
```

This helps me keep my methods nice and clean, so now I have 3 short methods that build a URL and return the RACSignal. The nice thing here is I can create side-effects to parse the JSON and assign the appropriate properties (note: I'm using [Mantle](https://github.com/github/Mantle) here).

```objc
- (RACSignal *)fetchCurrentConditions {
    // build URL
    return [[self fetchJSONFromURL:url] doNext:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        // simply converts JSON to a Mantle object
        self.currentCondition = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[CurrentCondition class] fromJSONDictionary:json error:nil];
    }];
}

- (RACSignal *)fetchHourlyForecast {
    // build URL
    return [[self fetchJSONFromURL:url] doNext:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        // more work
    }];
}

- (RACSignal *)fetchDailyForecast {
    // build URL
    return [[self fetchJSONFromURL:url] doNext:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        // more work
    }];
}
```

Finally, in the `-init` of my singleton, I set up the RAC observers on location, since every time the location changes I want to fetch and update the weather.

```objc
[[RACObserve(self, currentLocation)
 filter:^BOOL(CLLocation *newLocation) {
     return newLocation != nil;
 }] subscribeNext:^(CLLocation *newLocation) {
     [[RACSignal merge:@[[self fetchCurrentConditions], [self fetchDailyForecast], [self fetchHourlyForecast]]] subscribeError:^(NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
     }];
 }];
```

Everything works just fine, but I'm concerned that I'm straying from the Reactive way to structure my fetches and property assignments. I tried doing sequencing with `-then:` but wasn't really able to get that setup how I would like.

I was also trying to find a clean way to bind the result of an async fetch to the properties of my singleton, but ran into trouble getting that to work. I wasn't able to figure out how to "extend" the fetching `RACSignal`s (note: that's where the `-doNext:` idea came from for each of those).

Any help clearing this up or resources would be really great. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems inappropriate for `-fetch` methods to have meaningful side effects, which makes me think that your `WeatherManager` class is conflating two different things:

1. Network requests for getting the latest data
2. The stateful storage and presentation of that data

This is important because the first concern is stateless, while the second is almost entirely stateful. In GitHub for Mac, for example, we use [OCTClient](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.objc/blob/master/OctoKit/OCTClient.h) to perform the networking, and then store the returned user data on a "persistent state manager" singleton.

Once you break it down like this, I think it'll be easier to understand. Your state manager can interact with the networking client to kick off requests, and then the state manager can subscribe to those requests and apply side effects.

First of all, let's make the `-fetch…` methods stateless, by rewriting them to use transformations instead of side effects:

```
- (RACSignal *)fetchCurrentConditions {
    // build URL
    return [[self fetchJSONFromURL:url] map:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        return [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[CurrentCondition class] fromJSONDictionary:json error:nil];
    }];
}
```

Then, you can use these stateless methods and inject side effects into them where it's more appropriate:

```
- (RACSignal *)updateCurrentConditions {
    return [[self.networkClient
        // If this signal sends its result on a background thread, make sure
        // `currentCondition` is thread-safe, or make sure to deliver it to
        // a known thread.
        fetchCurrentConditions]
        doNext:^(CurrentCondition *condition) {
            self.currentCondition = condition;
        }];
}
```

And, to update all of them, you can use `+merge:` (like in your example) combined with `-flattenMap:` to map from the location values to a new signal of work:

```
[[[RACObserve(self, currentLocation)
    ignore:nil]
    flattenMap:^(CLLocation *newLocation) {
        return [RACSignal merge:@[
            [self updateCurrentConditions],
            [self updateDailyForecast],
            [self updateHourlyForecast],
        ]];
    }]
    subscribeError:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
```

Or, to automatically cancel in-flight updates whenever `currentLocation` changes, replace `-flattenMap:` with `-switchToLatest`:

```
[[[[RACObserve(self, currentLocation)
    ignore:nil]
    map:^(CLLocation *newLocation) {
        return [RACSignal merge:@[
            [self updateCurrentConditions],
            [self updateDailyForecast],
            [self updateHourlyForecast],
        ]];
    }]
    switchToLatest]
    subscribeError:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
```

*(Original reply from [ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#786](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/786)).*

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty complex question and I think you only need a few pointers to get it straightened out.

1. Instead of subscribing explicitly for the location, you may try to reformulate with a  `RACCommand`
2. You can bind a signal to a property with the `RAC` macro `RAC(self.currentWeather) = currentWeatherSignal;`
3. This tutorial is a great example of how you can implement network fetching in a clean way http://vimeo.com/65637501
4. Try to keep your business logic signals around and not set them up every time the event happens. The video tutorial shows a very elegant way to do this.

Remark: is it intentional that you stop location updates in the location updated callback? You may not be able to restart it in future versions of iOS. (*This is crazy and I'm raging because of it too.*)

Comment: Do you have any references to the location update logic? I'm assuming you're referring to something in iOS 7, if so I'm totally unaware of this. If that's true I will explode.

Comment: Checked with iOS 7, not having any issues with CLLocationManager. Works the same in iOS 6 and 7. Curious what your remark is about.

Comment: I haven't confirmed it yet but in a WWDC video it was mentioned that the GPS location updates will not be possible to be started if the app is backgrounded. E.g. on a significant update you can easily start the GPS in iOS6. This is theoretically not possible in iOS7. If you can confirm that it can still be started from the background, then they have changed this policy which is good for all of us.